# clearInterval within the interval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a interval set up like this:

```
var inte = setInterval(function(){
        clearInterval(inte);
    },1000);
```

Is there a way that i can do it like this?

```
setInterval(function(){
        clearInterval(this);
    },1000);
```

Comment: That is not a duplicate. I know how to stop it when the interval is attached to a variable, i just rather don't use a variable since i'm switching between 0 to zero intervals at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd need to wrap `setInterval` in your own `mySetInterval` that keeps track of the clearable id:

```
function mySetInterval(f,t) {
  var x =
    setInterval(
      function() {
        f();
        clearInterval(x);
      },
      t 
    )
}

mySetInterval(function() { alert("foo"); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Good enough for what i need. Still a but messy. but it works.. :p

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be running this only once, why not use `setTimeout` instead?

```
setTimeout(function(){
   // do your stuff here
}, 1000);
```

No need to clear anything in this case.

Comment: It's going to run more than once in real life. I wanted to keep the example simple.

Answer (score 0):

Store the function inside a variable. Then you can use the native .apply()  function to apply arguments and set the functions 'this' variable. Google should know some examples on .apply(), but why don't you use setTimeout(function(){},1000)? Then you wouldn't need to clear an interval because this only gets executed once.